# Wireless channel implementation in VEINS

Tags: omnet++, veins

Where the channel is implemented in VEINS? (file names etc)
What is the type of the channel that is implemented in VEINS?
Are all the channel parameters accessible?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by “type of channel” (e.g., can you give an example type that you would expect?). What do you mean by “all parameters”? Again, which parameter would you expect to be accessible?

Comment: @ChristophSommer thanks alot for the reply. Providing the link of the omnetpp manual, [link] (https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-ref:channels). In section 3.5 of omnetpp manual, types of channel are defined. Each channel has parameters such as delay, disable, ber, per etc. I was wondering if veins has implemented dataratechannel for wireless communication? and if the "disable" parameter is implemented? Similarly, how can we add more parameters to the channel? Parameters are also explained in section 2.1.4 Modeling of Packet Transmissions.

Comment: Channels in OMNeT++ are point to point communication facilities and have nothing to do with wireless channel models in Veins/INET etc. The wireless communication medium is usually modeled by a top level module in the simulation that coordinates the reception/transmission of all radios in the simulation.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by @Rudi is spot on. In more detail, the wireless channel model of Veins (as of version 5.1) determines reachability of nodes, communication delay, bit error rates, etc. according to transmission parameters, where network nodes are in relation to each other, buildings, and many more parameters. You can freely influence all of these parameters in a simulation.

Comment: Sorry i am new to omnet/veins so i didn't understand the explanation provided above. I would be happy if you answer my questions one by one as below,
 
Question 1: Which channel is implemented in veins (according to omnet's manual there are three channels types 'ideal channel', 'delay channel', 'dataratechannel')?

Question 2: Our assumption is dataratechannel is used. if so the parameters such as delay, disabled, ber, per etc should be available? our intention is to access the disable parameter and change the default value from false to true to activate that. need your suggestions.

Comment: How i find more information on 'the wireless channel and it parameters' that is implemented in Veins? Thanks a lot for your help and continued guidance. Really appreciate that.

Comment: The most recent version of the channel model is documented in 10.1109/VNC.2018.8628350 which is accessible via https://www.cms-labs.org/bib/bronner2018multichannel/